# Media Library uploaded images don't get the derivatives generated with the Image Style Warmer module

Tags: 8, media

I am using Drupal's Image Style Warmer module to generate derivatives for images uploaded to Drupal. But it is only working if the images are uploaded through "Content->Media" tab. I was trying on my localhost.

For images uploaded though the pages themselves using Media Library, when running the Image Style Warmer, it does not create derivative images.

Did notice that for images uploaded through Media Library the permissions look like below (seems I don't have read permission)

[image: image permission for upload from Media Library]

For images uploaded through Content->Media tab it has below permissions (these images work). It had my username listed with all permissions.

[image: image uploaded through Content->Media tab]

Both images were created in same folder. So Why does the images have different permissions? also how do they get set? and how would it be fixed (i mean what permissions to set where?)